# razor_imu_9dof razor-pub.launch error

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, razor-imu-9dof

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the Open_Log Artemis IMU DEV-16832

When I run roslaunch razor_imu_9dof razor-pub.launch

I get the error below:

```
[**INFO] [1643203227.324861]: Flushing first 200 IMU entries...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/melodic/share/razor_imu_9dof/nodes/imu_node.py", line 220, in
line = bytearray(ser.readline()).decode("utf-8")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 0: invalid start byte
[imu_node-2] process has died**
```

How do I resolve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395152/razor_imu_9dof-razor-pub.launch-error/) by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 34 on 2022-01-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-27**:
Hi @chm007 please avoid posting in forum and raise issue at the same time: https://github.com/ENSTABretagneRobotics/razor_imu_9dof/issues/63

**Comment by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on 2022-01-27**:
Morning Osliva, are you saying not to post these types of errors here, instead I should open an issue on github? I thought any ROS-package-related errors could be posted here for input from the community's experience.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-27**:
If you post and raise an issue at the same time you are impacting developer time. Answerers are doing this voluntary and if they spend time looking to resolve your issue to find later it was package related and that you already raised the issue it will be unproductive

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-27**:
When you raised an issue it means it’s package specific, therefore the contributors of that package are better suited to resolve

**Comment by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on 2022-01-27**:
Ah...understood thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reinstalling the package fixed the issue.

---

Originally posted by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) with karma: 34 on 2022-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0